# websockets from common lisp

Tags: websocket, common-lisp

I want my web application to  push live updates notifications to the clients.
I use common lisp and hunchentoot on ccl.
What libraries I should use?

I have found clws and hunchensockets.

Latter one is not recommended for production use.
I need production level code.

For the first one, clws, at the github there is an example. But I could not figure out how to send data to the client without sending a message from the client and by just opening socket connection form the client.

Seemingly there is not much difference from the classical http style, iff client requests then server responses. What am i missing there?

Comment: who recommends against hunchensockets for production use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should use the

```
write-to-client-text
```

or

`write-to-clients-text` to send server initiated responses to the client, for one client and many or all of them, respectively.

one should first have list of clients that is connected to the resource created at the examples, by creating a class for the resource like that.

```
(defclass echo-resource (ws-resource)
  ((clients :initform () :accessor clients)))
```

what is not mentioned in the examples there is to name this resource instance once defined to later use it.

```
(setf res1 (make-instance 'echo-resource))

(register-global-resource "/echo"
                          res1
                          (origin-prefix "http://127.0.0.1" "http://localhost"))
```

then you can gather the list of the connected clients to this resource by `clients` accessor of the class `echo-resource`

```
(clients res1)
```

now the functions I mentioned at top can be used from this package like that

```
(write-to-client-text (car (clients res1)) "new message to one")
(write-to-clients-text (clients res1) "<p id='mesagetoall'>new message to all</a>")
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a trick for finding example code:

https://github.com/search?l=common-lisp&q=defsystem+clws&ref=searchresults&type=Code

Of course, these examples vary in quality.

A similar approach may to work at other larger code hosting services.

Comment: I have looked the example in the first one. The js parts was missing. I have completed them. And my example works. But the connection example here is like normal http iff request then response pattern. I think in web sockets it was possible to write to the once opened socket by client from the server. I mean it should be possible initiated by the server. For example some user of an app send input to server by http and server saves to db, and the server also writes to the socket once opened so without client's initiation data is pushed to this client. Can this be attained by web socket/clws?